# can't publish user achievements

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This has been driving me mad for quite a while now but apparently I'm not the only one. I keep getting the Requires extended permission: publish_actions  error when I try to publish an achievement for a user. I'm using RestFB in Java to post to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/achievements?achievement=YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_URL&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I've set the requested permission for the app.

I've registered the achievement and the url I'm using is where it is located. I've checked I'm using the right token and url etc.

I've checked that the extended auth dialogue is enabled.

I've checked that the app is of type game.

I should probably point out that I am trying to publish to tests users accounts. I tried removing and re adding the test users but still doesn't work.

I've also seen something mentioned about creating a working aggregation page for the achievements. When I try to create an aggregation page then I don't seem to be able to choose Game Achievements in the "Data to Display" dialogue. I've tried publish but that didn't work. When I try and preview the aggregation then it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What permissions does `/me/permissions` list when queried using your current access token?

Comment: Strangely it works on my personal account but not my test users. On  my personal account I have not granted the permissions! @CBroe will try that and post back

Comment: So when I run that query the permissions are indeed not there, only {"data":[{"installed":1,"bookmarked":1}]}  , not sure how I can change this though, re adding the users to the app didn't do it